# sshd seems to ignore pam auth section when authorizing through private key

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, pam

I configure ssh authorization to drop some users with rules, defined in script, and also give them some extended capabilities when they login. I use two pam modules - pam_script and pam_cap and change sshd pam config (/etc/pam.d/sshd) so it looks like that (only first two lines are custom):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_script.so
auth       required     pam_cap.so
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

Password authentication is allowed, and now user can authorize through Pkey or password. If user authorizes through password, pam_script works well, and those users who doesn't stand rules are dropped. But, if same user authorizes through Pkey, then pam auth section seems to be bypassed, pam_script is not invoked at all. Doesn't sshd use pam auth when authorizing users with Pkey?

Answer (score 0):

PAM is used as a KeyboardAuthentication subsystem and is not invoked by PubkeyAuthentication.
You may drop user at session creation instead of authentication.